# custom options values from $_option object in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have added three `custom options` for the product in **magento1.9.0.1**. They are

```
Title: Brand, type: drop down, values: b1, b2, b3
Title: Model, type: drop down, values: m1, m2, m3
Title: Color, type: drop down, values: c1, c2, c3
```

In product page I have to use the values of custom option `Brand`. The `$_option` object contain all details of product. From the `$_option` object I have to retrieve the `Brand values` only. 
I want to display `b1, b2, b3`.

Using `$_option->getId();` I can get the `custom option id`. `$_option->getTitle()` gives the `title` of the `custom option.`

How to get the `particular custom option values` from `$_option object` (i know its custom option id).

Please help me...

Comment: is $_option object of product collection.?